# ProxyPass redirecting internally

Tags: apache, nexus, proxypass

I'm trying to set up two Apache ProxyPass rules to direct to different Nexus servers.  What I want is:

`http://mainserver/nexus` -> `http://server1:8080/nexus`

and

`http://mainserver/nexus-pro` -> `http://server2:8081/nexus`

I had it set up to work with our original server, but adding a second rule causes requests for nexus-pro to redirect to the main apache server with /nexus, which then forwards on to the wrong server, thus:

`http://mainserver/nexus-pro` -> `http://mainserver/nexus` -> `http://server1:8080/nexus`

I imagine this is something Nexus is doing itself, but I'm not really in control of that.

Here is my current Apache config, what do I need to change?

```
ProxyPass /nexus http://server1:8080/nexus
ProxyPassReverse /nexus http://server1:8080/nexus

ProxyPass /nexus-pro http://server2:8081/nexus
ProxyPassReverse /nexus-pro http://server2:8081/nexus

ProxyPreserveHost On
```

Comment: Try reversing the definitions.   Place ProxyPass /nexus-pro before ProxyPass /nexus.  Apache should process that one first

Comment: This didn't solve the problem - I still get sent to the Nexus server on server1.

Comment: Try the second answer to test the configuration.  I just verified that this works.  Make sure you are reloading your httpd configuration.

Comment: Hmmm... this times out and then gives a 503.  I should have mentioned that my Apache server sits behind a proxy.  I'll re-do your example, but proxying internal sites and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, this works fine.  So is the problem that Nexus is redirecting to /nexus at some point, causing the second ProxyPass rule to be applied?

Comment: Use browser debugger (firebug,chrome,ie dev tools) watch watch the network req/resp to see if there are any redirects that aren't being handled.  You may be able to work around the problem with RewriteRule.

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite was going to be my next step, thanks for all your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Within a given section, Apache httpd configurations are processed in the order in which they appear in the configuration.  If you transpose the two definitions,  the more explicit  /nexus-pro will override the /nexus definition.

```
ProxyPass /nexus-pro http://server2:8081/nexus
ProxyPassReverse /nexus-pro http://server2:8081/nexus

ProxyPass /nexus http://server1:8080/nexus
ProxyPassReverse /nexus http://server1:8080/nexus

ProxyPreserveHost On
```

Read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two lines for testing:

```
ProxyPass /example-ip http://www.toolsvoid.com/what-is-my-ip-address
ProxyPassReverse /example-ip http://www.toolsvoid.com/what-is-my-ip-address

ProxyPass /example http://www.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /example http://www.example.com/
```